# How can you write a scope in rails that does not capture a particular record but all others

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this scope, it works great:

```
scope :concurrent, lambda{ |a,r,e| where(application_id: a, role_id: r, environment_id: e) }
```

It's used like this:

```
l = Deployment.last
concurrent_deployments = Deployment.concurrent(l.application_id, l.role_id, l.environment_id)
```

I need to modify it so that it doesn't capture the Deployment that all the concurrents are concurrent with.  So I can add a parameter, *i* , which is the id of the target.

I rewrite:

```
scope :concurrent, lambda{ |a,r,e,i| where(application_id: a, role_id: r, environment_id: e, id: !i) }
```

This doesn't work.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you have two scopes?

```
scope :concurrent, lambda{ |a,r,e| where(application_id: a, role_id: r, environment_id: e) }
scope :concurrentx, lambda{ |a,r,e,i| where('application_id = ? AND role_id = ? AND environment_id = ? AND id <> ?',a,r,e,i) }
```